# Jekyll posts broken after adding SSL cert

Tags: jekyll

I just added an ssl cert to my website and now my posts are returning a 404. I've tried looking at my config file for clues but have yet to find anything. Could someone help me out here?

https://github.com/cbsedgley/sedgley.io

Comment: are you using the build in server or something else? and did you set the server to run with ssl?

Comment: all webpages except those under /blog and _posts are running properly. The index.html for /blog isn't pulling the proper CSS for the heading and all the posts are coming back 404. Not sure what's wrong.